# Spring bean validation without using @valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have used spring validation in the conventional way like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="userRegistration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUser(@Valid UserAccountVO userAccountVO, BindingResult result,Model model){
    if (result.hasErrors()){
    // Do something
    }
//Do something else
}
```

That works well and good.

But now I have case where I can't do a form submission, but instead get values in javascript and send them using Ajax on click of a button, something like this.

```
var nameStr = $("#usrnmbx").val();
var emailidStr = $("#emailidbx").val()
//and more and then send them using ajax
```

So to implement bean validation my new method looks something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userRegistration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JSONresponse registerUser(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value = "name") String name, // and more){

UserAccountVO userAccountVO = new UserAccountVO(name, emailId,password, confirmPassword);
BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(userAccountVO,"userAccount");
userAccountValidator.validate(userAccountVO, result); //userAccountValidator is spring Validator implementation 
if (result.hasErrors()) {
 //Do something
}
//Do something else
}
```

But this looks dirty. I definitely think there are better ways of doing this. And this doesn't seem like picking up the validation annotations that I have put up in the POJO. 
Can any of you suggest a better implementation. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can submit whole form with ajax. In this case your command object should be populated as ordinary form submission.

here is my aproach

```
        function submitAjaxForm(form, url) {  
        $.post(url, $(form).serialize(),function(data) {
              ...........
            }); 
}
```